# AdMob in iOS app - Collected user data deletion

Tags: swift, swiftui, admob, standards-compliance

New to AdMob and trying to understand compliance as it relates to providing and deleting collected user data to a user upon request from purely programming standpoint.
In my research, it appears that there is an API for the user to at least delete the data. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/userdeletion/v3/ being the most helpful so far though not specifically particularly helpful in code examples.  This would probably be accomplished either by the developer using the client ID manually or via the developer's app -> user deletion API.

Assuming one of the two approaches is the proper way the industry is currently handling this, how is this typically handled in Swift (ideally via SwiftUI not UIKit but I can follow along either way)?  Please note I am not asking how to set up AdMob in general, or how to use UMP to provide GDPR consent, or what anything related to legal/compliance beyond programming.

If there is some other, more preferred option, please let me know that as well.

Thus far I have researched the differences in client ID and user ID from an end user perspective.  Code-wise, I am unsure where to start until understanding which approach to take as dictated by the answers above.  I have also looked into exposing the client ID vs various items that might be used as a generic device ID but am unsure how best to obtain this as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Nobody here can tell you how to comply with legal requirements. SO is for questions about programming. Code, algorithms, etc.

Comment: Understood.  I'm asking what professional programmers are doing in their apps currently (intercepting client ID and assisting manually which is yet another data collection vs implementing the API so that the user can be in charge of requesting the record/deletion of datas).  I'm aware of what my legal requirements are just not how to programmatically implement them.

Comment: Edited my question to make it more explicitly clear what my programming specific goals are.